# my app consumes mega amount of cached background process

Tags: android

I have an android app that has 100 images in the drawable folder. Each activity uses around 10 images, and after I open like 10 different activities my cached background process consumes like 200mb. Even tho priror activities are closed the cached background process is huge.
I have already read about cached background process and I know it's not that serious issue, but in my case it takes around 200mb which is huge for me. 
Should I be worried and how can I deal with it?

EDIT: to add a code
I am using a class which has static instances and it's being used in another activity

```
public class BazaNaPrasanja{

// to create a database
static public VozackaDbHelper vozackaDbHelper;
// to use the database
static public SQLiteDatabase database;

// cursor used for the table in the database
static public Cursor cursorZnaci4;

public BazaNaPrasanja(Context context)
{
    vozackaDbHelper = new VozackaDbHelper(context);
    database = vozackaDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void queryCursorZnaci4()
{
    cursorZnaci4 = database.query(VozackaDbContract.TABLE_NAME_ZNACI4,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    cursorZnaci4.moveToFirst();
}
}
```

and activity which uses the class created with static instances

public class Znaci4  extends Activity{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle b)
{
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.znaci_4);

    int columnIndexPrasanje = BazaNaPrasanja.cursorZnaci4.getColumnIndex(VozackaDbContract.COLUMN_NAME_PRASANJE);
    int columnIndexSlika1 = BazaNaPrasanja.cursorZnaci4.getColumnIndex(VozackaDbContract.COLUMN_NAME_SLIKA1);
    int columnIndexSlika2 = BazaNaPrasanja.cursorZnaci4.getColumnIndex(VozackaDbContract.COLUMN_NAME_SLIKA2);
    int columnIndexSlika3 = BazaNaPrasanja.cursorZnaci4.getColumnIndex(VozackaDbContract.COLUMN_NAME_SLIKA3);
    int columnIndexSlika4 = BazaNaPrasanja.cursorZnaci4.getColumnIndex(VozackaDbContract.COLUMN_NAME_SLIKA4);
    int columnIndexOdgovor1 = BazaNaPrasanja.cursorZnaci4.getColumnIndex(VozackaDbContract.COLUMN_NAME_ODGOVOR1);
    int columnIndexOdgovor2 = BazaNaPrasanja.cursorZnaci4.getColumnIndex(VozackaDbContract.COLUMN_NAME_ODGOVOR2);
    int columnIndexOdgovor3 = BazaNaPrasanja.cursorZnaci4.getColumnIndex(VozackaDbContract.COLUMN_NAME_ODGOVOR3);
    int columnIndexOdgovor4 = BazaNaPrasanja.cursorZnaci4.getColumnIndex(VozackaDbContract.COLUMN_NAME_ODGOVOR4);
    int columnIndexOdgovor5 = BazaNaPrasanja.cursorZnaci4.getColumnIndex(VozackaDbContract.COLUMN_NAME_ODGOVOR5);
    int columnIndexOdgovor6 = BazaNaPrasanja.cursorZnaci4.getColumnIndex(VozackaDbContract.COLUMN_NAME_ODGOVOR6);

// a textview that is getting the text from the database and sets it's text to it
    TextView prasanjeTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prasanjeTV);
    String prasanjeStr = BazaNaPrasanja.cursorZnaci4.getString(columnIndexPrasanje);
    prasanjeTV.setText(prasanjeStr);

// imageview that gets the name of the drawable from the database and sets the background to that resource
    ImageView slika1IV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.slika1);
    String slika1Str = BazaNaPrasanja.cursorZnaci4.getString(columnIndexSlika1);
    int slika1Ref = this.getResources().getIdentifier(slika1Str,"drawable", getPackageName());
    slika1IV.setBackgroundResource(slika1Ref);

    ImageView slika2IV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.slika2);
    String slika2Str = BazaNaPrasanja.cursorZnaci4.getString(columnIndexSlika2);
    int slika2Ref = this.getResources().getIdentifier(slika2Str,"drawable", getPackageName());
    slika2IV.setBackgroundResource(slika2Ref);

    ImageView slika3IV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.slika3);
    String slika3Str = BazaNaPrasanja.cursorZnaci4.getString(columnIndexSlika3);
    int slika3Ref = this.getResources().getIdentifier(slika3Str,"drawable", getPackageName());
    slika3IV.setBackgroundResource(slika3Ref);

    ImageView slika4IV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.slika4);
    String slika4Str = BazaNaPrasanja.cursorZnaci4.getString(columnIndexSlika4);
    int slika4Ref = this.getResources().getIdentifier(slika4Str,"drawable", getPackageName());
    slika4IV.setBackgroundResource(slika4Ref);


// textview just getting value from database and sets it's text to it
    TextView odgovor1TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.odgovor1TV);
    String odgovor1Str = BazaNaPrasanja.cursorZnaci4.getString(columnIndexOdgovor1);
    odgovor1TV.setText(odgovor1Str);

    TextView odgovor2TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.odgovor2TV);
    String odgovor2Str = BazaNaPrasanja.cursorZnaci4.getString(columnIndexOdgovor2);
    odgovor2TV.setText(odgovor2Str);

    TextView odgovor3TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.odgovor3TV);
    String odgovor3Str = BazaNaPrasanja.cursorZnaci4.getString(columnIndexOdgovor3);
    odgovor3TV.setText(odgovor3Str);

    TextView odgovor4TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.odgovor4TV);
    String odgovor4Str = BazaNaPrasanja.cursorZnaci4.getString(columnIndexOdgovor4);
    odgovor4TV.setText(odgovor4Str);

    TextView odgovor5TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.odgovor5TV);
    String odgovor5Str = BazaNaPrasanja.cursorZnaci4.getString(columnIndexOdgovor5);
    odgovor5TV.setText(odgovor5Str);

    TextView odgovor6TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.odgovor6TV);
    String odgovor6Str = BazaNaPrasanja.cursorZnaci4.getString(columnIndexOdgovor6);
    odgovor6TV.setText(odgovor6Str);

}


// actually it start's the same activity just with different position of the cursor(with different data)
public void slednoPrasanje(View view) {
    BazaNaPrasanja.cursorZnaci4.moveToNext();
    int pos = BazaNaPrasanja.cursorZnaci4.getPosition();
    if(pos == 25) BazaNaPrasanja.cursorZnaci4.moveToFirst();
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Znaci4.class));
    finish();   // I destroy the old activity but the cached background proccess takes 200mb after I open 10 or less than it activities
}



}
```

}

some useless code is ommited just to save some space and not overwhelm you.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @breakline thanks for your suggestion, I added the code and some comments. also I ommited some useless code that could only overwhelm you.